# CodeIgniter Memcached session driver loss of session data

Tags: codeigniter

at:

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#memcached-driver

The documentation states:

However, it is worth noting that the only guarantee given by Memcached is that setting value X to expire after Y seconds will result in it being deleted after Y seconds have passed (but not necessarily that it won’t expire earlier than that time). This happens very rarely, but should be considered as it may result in loss of sessions.

Does this mean users could lose their data while logged in? I guess I don't understand why this would happen. I cannot risk users losing their session data. Should I use Redis instead? Does redis have same problem?